# android showing below error after adding firebase auth dependency in gradle

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

[Below images shows error after adding firebase auth dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jO8FF.png)

Before adding fire base auth dependency it was working fine.After adding firebase auth dependency as given below  code of my build.gradle(app) where i added the dependency of firebase.auth.It's showing the given error.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'

    // Displaying images
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'

    //adding firebase database
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'

       // FirebaseUI for Firebase Realtime Database
       compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'

        // FirebaseUI for Cloud Firestore
        compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:3.1.0'

       // FirebaseUI for Firebase Auth
       compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'





}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: After you fix the file name length problem, you will likely also want to align the versions of FireaseUI, the Support libraries, and Firebase SDK libraries.  The instructions are in the [FirebaseUI documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#compatibility-with-firebase--google-play-services-libraries).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a Firebase issuse. `Failed to crunch` file which appear in your logcat, means that Android Studio can't process the file. Its path is too long and it has reached the maximum file path line of the operating system.

To solve this, need to make this as short as possible. It will resolve this error for sure. I recomand you have something like this:

```
D:\Resources\Firebase-Weekend\Project
```

Another approach will be to change the build directory of the project in the build.gradle file (Project) like this:

```
allprojects {
    buildDir = "C:/tmp/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}"
    //other lines
}
```